# Increase response time of MS SQL restore operations

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to restore multiple MS SQL databases using JDBC driver (java tool)

The response time is very slow, all the concurrent DBs seems stuck (but they are running)

Is there any way to increase the response time for the restore DB operation ?

I expect the restore DBs faster as much as can.

Comment: There is too little information in your question. Can you post more details as to what tool you are using? What restore times you are getting? What have you investigated in trying to find the root cause for this? What is the backup size etc.?

Comment: When I googled _t-sql speed up restore times_ this is the first link I got: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4935/optimize-sql-server-database-restore-performance/ did you try anything from here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the backup files you are restoring are not on the same drive your databases are on.